# Incorrect positioning between LG and MD

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

Please take a look at https://mgumerov.github.io/jquery/test.html
(there will be some queries https->http, don't you be scared by it)

In a thumbnails view mode, each tile is declared with `col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2`, and most of the time and with most window sizes it behaves well. However there are some window sizes which break the layout:

[image]

But still that depends on a specific page, I mean, page 1 can get ruined but page 2 will be OK.

So I wonder 1) why the supplied styles do not work as expected and 2) how do I fix that?

Comment: the test page doesn't show anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, It's a clearfix question :

Please look at the doc : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Look at this : http://www.bootply.com/uTgFw9yoTG

*This will appear with bad effect*

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">col</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">col</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">col</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">col</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">col</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">col</div>
</div>
```

*This will be good:*

```
<div class="container bis">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">col</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">col</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">col</div>
  <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">col</div>  
  <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">col</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">col</div>
</div>
```

You have to set a clearfix at every 12 col.

In this exemple, you have to add a clearfix visible only on md every 3 div. (md-4 x 3 = 12)

And add a clearfix visible only on lg every 4 div (lg-3 x 4 = 12).

Comment: I'd say that makes the markup rather messy. Do I take it right I could skip that if tile content height would be constant?

Comment: It's Exactly this ;-)